# Apache2: Index.html Loads on IP but not on Domain Name (Ubuntu)

Tags: html, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I made an AWS EC2 Instance and get an Elastic IP.

The Elastic IP was used to set a Domain Name (Bought from GoDaddy) to the AWS EC2 Instance.

The EC2 Instance is running an Apache2 server.

According to the manual, I'm supposed to replace index.html in /var/www/html/ with the index.html of my own, which I did.

When I use the Elastic IP, the index.html page that I set is displayed.

However when I use the Domain Name, for some reason it gives me the default apache2 page, even though that file no longer exists since it was overwritten. I can access the index.html with `DomainName.in/index.html`.

Simply put :

 - DomainName.in gives apache2 default index.html which shouldn't exist anymore

 - DomainName.in/index.html gives the page that I want to show up

 - ElasticIP and ElasticIP/index.html both give the page I want to show up

How can I make it so that just typing the Domain Name in the browser will take me to the index.html page that I want it to go to ?

Comment: What does you nginx configuration look like?

Comment: I didn't use an nginx configuration, it's just an EC2 instance with apache2 and a Domain Name mapped to it using Elastic IPs. Decided to start off simply before adding nginx.

Comment: You need to set the`DirectoryIndex index.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so it turns out everything is fine, but the changes take time to propagate through the DNS for some reason.

The changes register after about half an hour.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set DirectoryIndex in your virtualhost configuration which is located here: `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

If that is not where your config file is located, you can find it by running: `/usr/sbin/apache2 -V | grep SERVER_CONFIG_FILE`

```
<virtualhost *:80>

  ServerName  domain.com
  ServerAlias www.domain.com

  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex home.html index.html
  DocumentRoot /var/www

</virtualhost>
```

Comment: Which file do I append this to ?

Comment: @MeghdeepRay there is a lot to setting up and properly configuring an Apache server. You need to look at some documentation. @soren468 you assume he is running a debian/ubuntu based system. If it's Centos/rhel none of those locations will help as they use httpd `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` you need to see what he's running.

Comment: It's Ubuntu 14.04, very standard stuff. So VirtualHosts is what I need to look up right ?